# validation for minimum two input fields should be filled out of 6 or more

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

here we have 6 inputs, where i'm looking for validation, if minimum 2 fileds are not filled it show alert esle submits the form in html.

```
<form  action="/" method="POST">
<p>
<input type="file" name="file1">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file2">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file3">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file4">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file5">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file6">
</p>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very basic question. So, very basic solution so that anyone can understand

Java script Code

```
        function showValidationError() {
            var counter = 0;

            if (document.getElementById("file1").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("file2").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("file3").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("file4").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("file5").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("file6").value != "") {
                counter++;
            }

            if (counter < 2) {
                alert('error');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file4" id="file4">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file5" id="file5">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file6"  id="file6">
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return showValidationError();">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put them in a class

```js
$("#regForm").submit(function(){
 let empty = 0;
 $( ".regInput" ).each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).get(0).files.length === 0) {
      empty++
    }
  });
  
  if (empty >= 2) {
    alert(empty + " inputs empty")
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="regForm"  action="/" method="POST">
<p>
<input type="file" name="file1"class="regInput">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file2" class="regInput">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file3" class="regInput">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file4" class="regInput">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file5" class="regInput">
</p>
<p>
<input type="file" name="file6" class="regInput">
</p>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add an event listener for `submit` on the form that loops through all file input fields and checks whether they are valid. This is done by checking the length of their `files` property. If they are, increment the valid field counter and after the loop check whether the number of valid fields is smaller than 3. If it is, prevent form submission with `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var validFields = 0;
  this.querySelectorAll('input:not([value])').forEach((e) => {
    if (e.files.length > 0) {
      validFields++;
    }
  })
  if (validFields < 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file2">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file3">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file4">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file5">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="file6">
  </p>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```